# Calling closure inside closure

Tags: swift, closures

This is my code:

```
var work: ((Int, completionHandler: (() -> ()) -> ()))?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    work(1, {
        // Does not work.
    })

    workAsMethod(amount: 1) {
        // Works.
    }

    work = { (amount, completionHandler) in
        // Does not work
        completionHandler()
    }

    return true
}

func workAsMethod(amount: Int, completionHandler: @escaping (() -> ())) {
    // Works
    completionHandler()
}
```

When I am using a method with a block that I can call to indicate work is done, it works. When I try to do the same thing within a closure (closure inside closure), I can not get it to work.

What is the correct syntax to call a closure inside a closure to notify the 'listener' that the work is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of your `work` closure needed work:

```
var work: ((Int, _ completionHandler: () -> ()) -> ())?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // Use optional chaining here to unwrap work before calling
    work?(1, {
        // This now works.
    })

    workAsMethod(amount: 1) {
        // Works.
    }

    work = { (amount, completionHandler) in
        // This now works
        completionHandler()
    }

    return true
}

func workAsMethod(amount: Int, completionHandler: @escaping (() -> ())) {
    // Works
    completionHandler()
}
```

`work` is an optional closure that takes an `Int` and a `() -> ()` and it returns nothing `-> ()`.

If you break down your type for `work`, your `completionHandler` has type `(() -> ()) -> ()` which means your `completionHandler` takes a `() -> ()` closure and returns nothing.  You want your `completerHandler` to take no parameters.  Because of the misplaced `(` and `)`, your `work` was actually an *optional tuple* and not a closure type.